# How do I fit a 2D scene into a QOpenGLWidget window using a shader program?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, qt5, shader

I am trying to fit an entire 2D scene of triangles into a window. I am using a shader program to handle drawing the triangles. I only a fraction of the 900 triangles I expect to see. However, when I use the deprecated OpenGL API to draw squares in a similar scene, it works as expected.

It must have somethig to do with the MVP matrix that I am passing into the vertex shader. See the `paintGL()` method in the [scene.cpp](https://github.com/dirthead/triangles/blob/master/scene.cpp) module. That is where I setup the `glViewport` and the `mvpMatrix` before drawing the triangles.

I have outlined what I have done below.

### Tools

- Linux
- Qt 5.11.1
- OpenGL ES

### Setup

1. The scene is 1M x 1M
2. 900 triangles are added to the scene using a shader program

   - It is a grid of 30 x 30 triangles evenly distributed in the scene

### Problem

- An attempt was made to fit the entire scene inside the window.
- The result was that only 75 out of the 900 triangles are visible in the window.

Here is a screenshot of the [triangles](https://github.com/dirthead/triangles/blob/master/triangles.png) demo.

#### Triangles demo source:

- The [scene.cpp](https://github.com/dirthead/triangles/blob/master/scene.cpp) module contains the `paintGL` method.
- The [triangles.cpp](https://github.com/dirthead/triangles/blob/master/triangles.cpp) module is where the shader program is setup and the triangles are constructed.
- The full source to the [triangles](https://github.com/dirthead/triangles) demo is on github.

### What worked

I found that using the deprecated OpenGL API, drawing squares using GL_QUADS, does what I am looking for. However, I would like to be using shaders.

Here is a screenshot of the [squares](https://github.com/dirthead/squares/blob/master/squares.png) demo. It is a grid of 10 x 10 squares in a 1M x 1M scene.

#### Squares demo source:

- The full source to the [squares](https://github.com/dirthead/squares) demo is on github.

Comment: A very broad question. Can't you narrow it down for specific source codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug. It was in [triangles.cpp](https://github.com/dirthead/triangles/blob/master/triangles.cpp) where I was allocating the VBO. I was using the wrong byte count.

Changing:

```
_vertexBuffer.allocate(_vertexes, _vertexCount);
```

to:

```
_vertexBuffer.allocate(_vertexes, _vertexCount * sizeof(QVector3D));
```

fixed the problem.